# Redis Data Loss

Tags: node.js, redis, data-loss

We are using Node.JS in combination with Redis and we are having data loss issue.
We have statistics collection system, so we must collect each request dealt to our server.
With high concurrent requests (avg 1000/sec) we have data loss problems in Redis.

We have logged every request in Node.JS & Redis, the problem is that Node.JS shows exact the same amount of requests that were sent, Redis Monitor debugs the same amount, but Redis DBSIZE shows to us incorrect value. It is always ~40%-50% less than expected.

Our sever configuration is :

```
Intel® Core™ i7-920
24 GB DDR3 RAM
From Hetzner
```

We are running Debian Squeeze, here is our sysctl:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net.core.somaxconn = 1280
fs.file-max = 50000
vm.overcommit_memory=1
```

We have "load average" of 0.04, and plenty of free memory (~20gb).

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to review the Redis configuration regarding memory management.
Depending on the values of the maxmemory and maxmemory-policy parameters, Redis can evict objects from memory. You may want to check that maxmemory entry is commented out, and maxmemory-policy is not set to allkeys-*

Then the Node.js code should be reviewed as well. Node.js being asynchronous, it can push a large number of items to Redis before processing the corresponding ack packets from Redis. The code should be designed to limit the number of items in the client command queue at some point. You can count and compare the number of sent commands with the number of replies (to be calculated by defining callbacks) to check this point.

Finally, you may also want to use the [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command of Redis to check that all the traffic really sent to the Redis server is indeed stored. It may help to evaluate if the problem is on server side or client side.

Comment: I think i figured out that Node.JS indeed seems to be the problem, or to be more exact, Node.JS redis driver, node_redis.

We have moved to mysql memory indeed, it gives pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, `DBSIZE` is supposed to return ALL Keys? Have you tried the same with the `KEYS` command?

Edit:
This might help as well.
[Accuracy of redis dbsize command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219107/accuracy-of-redis-dbsize-command)

Comment: KEYS command returns the same number as DBSIZE, incorrect number.