# I have a docker container with a Redis database. How do I know if the database has data?

Tags: docker, redis

I have taken over a position in a company where the developers have left and I am trying to get a legacy system up and running. I have two containers for the nodejs application and redis database which were created by the docker-compose.yml file. The containers are up and running with a few warnings. When I run the command 'Docker ps' I get the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS          PORTS                                NAMES
ef575204dfc8   node:16.19-alpine     "node ./app/app.js -…"   2 days ago   Up 15 seconds   0.0.0.0:20000->13001/tcp             server-node-service-1
47efad61a584   redis:4.0.11-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 16 seconds   6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20001->26379/tcp   server-node-redisdb-1
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  redisdb:
    #name: nowce-developdb
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    volumes:
     - ../database/redis/provider/${PROVIDER_ID}:/data
    ports:
     - "20001:26379"
    restart: unless-stopped

  service:
    image: node:16.19-alpine
    #restart: always
    working_dir: /home/node
    entrypoint: "node ./app/app.js --env production"
    mem_limit: "300M"
    memswap_limit: "1G"
    ports:
     - "20000:13001"
    volumes:
     - .:/home/node # modified here to take into account the new app path
    # - ./logs:/home/app/logs
    user: node
    links:
     - redisdb
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
     - AES=false
     - SERVICE_ROUTE=develop
     - PROVIDER_ID=${PROVIDER_ID}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX}
     - ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
     - ADMIN_EMAIL=${ADMIN_EMAIL}
     - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
     - PROVIDER_APIKEY=${PROVIDER_APIKEY}
     - INSTITUTION_CODE=${INSTITUTION_CODE}
     - CANDIDATE_URL=${CANDIDATE_URL}
     - CONTRIBUTOR_URL=${CONTRIBUTOR_URL}
```

When I run the command '`redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379`' I get the reply:

```
localhost:6379> DBSIZE
(integer) 0
```

I understand that this means there isn't any data in the Redis database in the container, but I am copying into the directory `\database\redis\provider\default_provider_1\` a file called dump.rdb that definitely has data in it. I copy it in when the containers have been stopped. Am I checking the wrong database at localhost:6379 or is there some other reason why I am not getting any data?

Comment: You can try `keys *`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219107/accuracy-of-redis-dbsize-command) the two don't always return the same results.

Comment: You should also check that you have the correct [database number](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-manage-redis-databases-and-keys#managing-databases).